# Invalid procedure call or argument (Inusual character in string chain, document from Power BI) VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a macro (Microsoft Excel) that copies a sheet from a local file that was downloaded from the cloud. This file has two columns that I want to convert to an XML file and then read it in another language.

The problem is that when I read the cell, this "?" symbol appears at the beginning of the string in debug mode, but when I see the original string, there is nothing. I already copied and pasted the string in Microsoft Word and activated the Show/Hide function and there a special character appears that I cannot see what it is even if I change the font (just appear a frame). And I put a conditional in the code that extracts that character, but I can't identify it to be able to eliminate or cut the original string and not get an error.

Any idea how to detect this or these characters? I even copied and pasted into the code, but nothing.

This is the code...

```
        With Workbooks(Wbook).Sheets(WSheetData)
            CM = .Range("B" & i).Value
            DESC = .Range("A" & i).Value
            FC = Left(DESC, 1)
            If FC = "" Then
                MsgBox "UNUSUAL"
            End If
        End With
```

Comment: Debug.Print is not reliable for non-ascii characters - you will need to (eg) write it to a worksheet cell or check the character code using `Asc(Left(DESC, 1))` or `AscW(Left(DESC, 1))`

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for your answer, that worked!!!. Thank you so much, my head was exploding.

Answer (score 1):

**@TimWilliams, thank for your time and effort.**

This is the code with the correction.

```
        With Workbooks(Wbook).Sheets(WSheetData)
            CM = .Range("B" & i).Value
            DESC = .Range("A" & i).Value
            FC = Asc(Left(DESC, 1))
            If FC = "63" Then
                DESC = Right(DESC, Len(DESC) - 1)
            End If
        End With
```

Comment: As `Asc` returns an `Integer`, it should be `If FC = 63 Then`. `DESC = Right(DESC, Len(DESC) - 1)` can be simiplified as `DESC = Mid$(DESC, 2)`.